# Reference request: Rigid body motion

Tags: reference-request, rigid-transformation

For a long time I have been wondering if there is some reference in which the motion of a rigid motion is systematically studied from a mathematical perspective; i.e., without using the conventional physical methods such as *relative motion* and *geometric mechanics.*

Briefly speaking, I'm looking for a book which studies the  motion of rigid bodies with differential geometry, and avoids the heavy use of physical principles.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid Physics?!

Comment: Because I have some difficulties digesting the basic physical principles, in other words, ( I know that this is not good) I don't like human's physical intuition, or something like that...

Comment: *I don't trust human's physical intuition*? you're kidding, right?

Comment: If you're looking for a mathematical treatise that builds analytical mechanics sufficiently from the ground up, I couldn't recommend Lanczos's Variational Principles of Mechanics highly enough.

Comment: There are several ways to compute the equations of motion for a rigid body. A popular and rigerous physical principle is based on the Lagrange equations (c.f. Lagrangian mechanics). Try, for example, 'Classical Mechanics of Particles and Rigid Bodies' - Gupta.

Comment: @Croco: In fact I am skeptical about the laws derived from the numerous experiences , since they are the result of practical observations. However, one might argue that mathematics is to some degree also an artificial work of human's brain, but I still prefer maths, since it's more self-consistent.

Comment: This is not exactly what you're asking for, but you may want to look at Osgood's [**Mechanics**](https://archive.org/details/mechanics032869mbp) (1937). (Yes, this is the *Osgood* who came up with a Jordan curve having positive measure, the *Osgood* who essentially came up with the Baire category theorem independently of Baire, etc.) There is also a [1951 English translation](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.zamlynska-3fcd4b46-3376-45e4-aec6-74da5969363e?q=bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-50796184-5cd5-4064-b87f-71e6fecb3d49;0&qt=CHILDREN-STATELESS) **(continued)**

Comment: of Banach's textbook on mechanics (Polish original published in 1938) --- see the bottom of [this web page](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-50796184-5cd5-4064-b87f-71e6fecb3d49?q=3a7884e7-2abe-4e4e-aa2b-79915ccc4dec$4&qt=IN_PAGE) for .pdf files of the chapters. (Yes, this is the *Banach* you're thinking of!) The reason I mention these two books is that they are likely to be careful with various mathematical aspects of the subject. I say "likely to be" because, although I've known about these books for many years, I have not examined them very closely.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro: Many thanks! These two books really help a lot.